# Explanation for two token accounts for one owner?

Tags: solana-program, spl-token, spl-token-program, spl-associated-token-account

These two token accounts have the same mint and owner.

https://explorer.solana.com/address/2xPnqU4bWhUSjZ74CibY63NrtkHHw5eKntsxf8dzwiid
https://explorer.solana.com/address/2pb9va1fRPzvgxj5w2P2Sqq2a5SQpWMbBD5fMYTNSifp

[image: 2xPnqU4bWhUSjZ74CibY63NrtkHHw5eKntsxf8dzwiid]

How did they make these accounts?

Running `spl-token create-account --owner 8x2uay8UgrLiX8AAYyF6AkK9z91nNtN6aLwfqPkf6TAQ EPjFWdd5AufqSSqeM2qN1xzybapC8G4wEGGkZwyTDt1v` gives below error because of mint authority mismatch.

```
Creating account G3F36PfmCyKG8yQH3fzFjpapTMjxN2Y1ZFWLh7HXkGTp
RPC response error -32002: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: custom program error: 0x2 [18 log messages]
```

While `G3F36PfmCyKG8yQH3fzFjpapTMjxN2Y1ZFWLh7HXkGTp` is PDA derived from owner and mint, how are `2xPnqU4bWhUSjZ74CibY63NrtkHHw5eKntsxf8dzwiid`, `2pb9va1fRPzvgxj5w2P2Sqq2a5SQpWMbBD5fMYTNSifp` generated?

Answer (score 1):

A user may own arbitrarily many token accounts belonging to the same mint.
Thats why Associated Token Account exists: https://spl.solana.com/associated-token-account

Comment: how can I generate those many token accounts?

Comment: Create random/Associated token account: https://yihau.github.io/solana-web3-demo/tour/create-token-account.html